# Log in ios app from user date in sql database

Tags: php, ios, sql, json

Im trying to create a application where the user must sign in.

```
    <?php
include ("./inc/connect.inc.php");
header('Content-type: application/json');
if($_POST) {
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Player WHERE FirstName='$user' AND LastName='$pass'";
$userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
    if ($userCount == 1) {
    echo '{"success":1}';
 } else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username and/or password is invalid."}';

}
}else {    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username and/or password is invalid."}';

}

?>
```

if i was to change the if $usercount = 1 part to if($_POST['username'] == 'steffgriff' && $_POST['password'] == 'password'). And then entered in on the application steffgriff and password it would work. Any ideas why it wont work as a count function. I'll put below my code in my app also

```
- (IBAction)signinClicked:(id)sender {
NSInteger success = 0;
@try {

    if([[self.txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Email and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];

    } else {
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.txtUsername text],[self.txtPassword text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.rugbycoachanalysis.com/jsonlogin.php"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

        if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error:&error];

            success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
            NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

            if(success == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }

        } else {
            //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
}
if (success) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
}
```

}

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting your `$user` and `$pass` variables from static strings, try retrieving them from the `$_POST` array, like this:

```
if($_POST) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    // Rest of your code
```